# Import Multipage TIFF as separate images in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm currently working on some image processing in python 2. I'm saving the images as a multipage .tif files, which contain 4 images of resolution 1920x1080. I've imported the tiff file using `skimage.io.imread`. Once I've done this, I'm left with an ndarray with shape (1080,1920,4). How should I break this into four separate 1920x1080 Numpy arrays that I could then use for image processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.dsplit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dsplit.html#numpy.dsplit):

```
arrays = numpy.dsplit(a, a.shape[2])
```

This will get you a list with the arrays you want.

Optionally you could just use slicing:

```
arrays = [a[:,:,n] for n in range(a.shape[2])]
```